# C++ comparing a character

Tags: c++, compare

I am having problems with comparing characters.

Comparing a string works:

```
(strBuffer.compare("false") == 0)
```

(where strBuffer is of type string)

but

```
char next = input->peek();
if(next.compare("'")== 0)
```

(I need to check if next is a single quote)

Error given:

```
error: request for member 'compare' in 'next', which is of non-class type 'char'
```

Comment: You know that `strBuffer=="false"` does the same thing but faster right?

Comment: In C++, chars are not the same as strings of length 1; Unlike the case in most languages. So they don't have "class methods" so to speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `char` is not `string`.

You have two options:

1. Easiest: just compare the char:

   ```
   if (next == '\'')
   ```

   Mind the single quotes here, which tell the compiler that you want a single character instead of a string.
2. Or convert the char to a string:

   ```
   std::string next(1, input.peek());
   if (next == "'")
   ```

   The `1` tells `std::string` how many of these characters you want to have. You can use `==` here (and for all comparisons involving `std::string`¹) instead of the compare method, which is much more readable.

The explanation of the error message: `char` is a primitive (non-class) type. So trying to access members of `char` (such as in your case, `compare`) isn't going to work, because `char` variables don’t have any members. A `char` is usually an eight bit wide integer, which happens to be representable in the programming language as an 8 bit character (you can also assign numbers to chars, like `char next = 10`).

---

1: It would not work if you used it like this: `if ("a" == "b")`, this would not do what you expect it to do (unspecified behaviour).

Comment: I'd say that even for his string OP should prefer `==`.

Comment: Thats a good point I thought about while reading the question, but not while writing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A char is a [primitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type), not an object (string). You can just compare it directly, with single quotes, which are used to denote single characters:

```
if (next == '\'') { ... }
```

The backslash is an escape character, which is needed since we are trying to check for the very character we are using as a delimiter.

And, to compare your string you could use the same syntax, but with double quotes:

```
if (strBuffer == "false") { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

That should work:

```
if(next == '\'')
{
   std::cout << "Got it" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly compare a character by using the `==` operator:

```
if(next == '\'')
```

Answer (score 0):

char next = input->peek();

```
if(next ==  '\'')
{
    //do something
}
```

you can also do:

```
if (strBuffer == "false")
{
    //do something
}
```